# Programmatically spread linearLayouts inside a constraint layout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-constraintlayout

I have problems programmatically adding linearlayouts, listItem, to a constraint layout. What I want is to evenly spread x number of listItem horizontally in the constraint layout.

The constraint layout contains a linearlayout, @+id/list, where I add views, listItem, to programmatically, but the behavior is not what i expect.

When I do this at run time, it seems like the listItem has set layout_width="wrap_content" and compresses all my added views to the left of the constraint view with no air between them.

If I add several listItem in the constraint xml file, it behaves as expected - evenly spread the listItems so they fill the whole width of the constrint view. Each listItem gets the same anount of space.

What have I done wrong?

Constraint layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/heading"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/na"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_normal"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/wtu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/na"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_normal"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/emergency_drugname" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/heading">
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

LinearLayout listItem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listItem"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/na"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_normal"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dose"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/na"
        android:textColor="#006600"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_normal"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/total_dose"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/na"
        android:textColor="#006600"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_normal"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Sounds like the problem is in your code, so you will need to show the code in your question. Are you [setting the constraints](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintSet) for the views you are adding?

Comment: I did not set the constraint settings progrmmatically. Nor did I when I but the listItem linear layouts inside the constraint XML-file etiher - and that worked.But I chose an other approach after banging my head against the keyboard for some hours. Maybe not the best solution, but it works.

Comment: Please do add your java code for inflating the layout

Comment: I went for another approach this time and I did not save the code that I used trying to spread LL inside a CL programmatically. I most likely try again later... :-)

Answer (score 0):

try to add this line to your item :

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

rather than :

```
    android:layout_width="0dp"
```

i hope it will work for you

Comment: In order for X number of listItem to spread evenly, layout_width should be set to 0dp and layout_weigth set to 1. If I use fill_parent, the behavior will be different than what I want.